# Can we omit the preposition "to" in the phrase "be responded to by"? And why?

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

In an article, I have read a sentence as follows:

> In the Golgi stress response, insufficient organelle capacity is responded to by augmentation of glycosylation enzyme expression and vesicular transport components.

I think that the sentence is similar to

> Insufficient organelle capacity is responded to the Golgi stress by augmentation of glycosylation enzyme expression and vesicular transport components.

I wonder whether I perceive the meaning correctly.
In addition, can we omit the preposition *to* in the original sentence, although I understand that we can not omit the preposition *to* in my adapted version of the sentence.  As an graduate from China, I also hope you can tell me more about the reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a hard time understanding your adapted version of the sentence. If I look at the original sentence, and I replace all the medical jargon that I do not understand, the sentence basically says that *in a certain process, something happens, and it gets a response*. So basically, this sentence is similar in construction:

> In the wedding ceremony, the minister's question is responded to by affirmative answers.

Now, your adaptation would be:

> *The minister's question is responded to the wedding ceremony by affirmative answers.

Which, honestly, makes little sense to me. Not only is this used of *responded to* not grammatical, but it *seems* that you now make something respond *to the ceremony*, instead of the question.

Let's take apart the original sentence:

> In the Golgi stress response, -> *During this process*
>   insufficient organelle capacity  -> *something (A) happens*
>   is responded to -> *something happens as a response to that*
>   by augmentation of glycosylation enzyme expression and vesicular transport components. -> *this (B) happens because (A) happened*

So simply said: **In this process, A is responded to by B**. The *to* cannot be left out, because *respond to* is idiomatic. It means that *B* happens *in response to* A, or B happens *because* A happened.

Your adaptation would mean:

> Insufficient organelle capacity -> *something (A) happens*
>    is responded to -> *because of (B)*
>   the Golgi stress -> *this is the reason for (A)*
>   by augmentation of glycosylation enzyme expression and vesicular transport components. -> *this is how (A) happens. Or (B). I really don't know*

Comment: Maybe, a passive way is different from an active way. For example, in the sentence you provided, is it proper if I revise the sentence in an active way by adding a subbject? In the wedding ceremony, someone responded to the minister's question by affirmative answers.

Comment: @deweili Yes, you can make it active. The main thing is that the response is to the question, not to the ceremony. So in your sentence, the response is to _insufficient organelle capacity_, not to _ the Golgi stress (response)_.